# How to clear a specific form input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are two text inputs in my html form:

```
 <form id="insert_amount",onsubmit="submitAmount();return false;"> 

        **input(type="text",placeholder="Your message",name="message")** 
        **input(type="text",placeholder="Your amount",name="amount")** 
        input(type="submit" value="Pay!!!")

 </form>
```

I would like to know how I can clear the input of only one of the forms using jquery (maybe by input name). Probably something similar to:

```
$('#insert_amount').children("input[name='amount']").reset();
```

And not just a total form reset like:

```
$('#insert_amount').reset();
```

Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[name=amount]').val('')`

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the textboxes

`(type="text",placeholder="Your message",name="message",id="message")`

Now you can just use a jquery selector on that id and clear the value of the input box

```
$("#message").val('');
```